# How to find total tweets of a user using twitter api v 1.1?

Tags: php, api, twitter

Hi i want to find total number tweets of a user for example [here](https://twitter.com/NithinPDev1) you can see the tweet count is 14.. I have api keys and all, I just want the api call.

I coded up to this

```
        $twitteruser = "Username";
        $notweets = 5000;
        $consumerkey = "#########################";
        $consumersecret = "###############################";
        $accesstoken = "####################################";
        $accesstokensecret = "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$";

        function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
          $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
          return $connection;
        }

        $connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

         //
        $following = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

        echo'<pre>'; echo count($following->ids);

        $followers = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

        echo'<pre>'; echo count($followers->ids);
```

I gets the `follwoers` count and `following` count now i want the total `tweet` count any idea how to get this?

Comment: Are you advertizing your profile or what ? Have you attempted to write any code ? Did you check the twitter API docs ?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: How did you get the keys, secrets and token?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this :

```
$user = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser);
$following = intval($user->friends_count);
$followers = intval($user->followers_count);
$tweets = intval($user->statuses_count);
```